# How is implemented the specialization of std::hash function for std::shared_ptr<T> type

Tags: c++11, hash

The following link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/hash

let me think that by default (without coding a proper operator () for ptime type) we can't have a `std::unordered_map` with `boost::posix::ptime` type as key, but we could have it with `std::shared_ptr<boost::posix::ptime>` type, is it true ?

How is implemented the hashing function for a shared_ptr? The input of the hash function is the raw adress 0xCBA... of the underlying pointer and the output the corresponding hash value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `std::map` doesn't use `std::hash` at all; I believe you were thinking of `std::unordered_map`.
2. The partial specialisation of `std::hash` for `std::shared_ptr` works by hashing the *pointer* value, not the value *pointed to.* And it's the same hash as would be obtained by hashing the raw pointer stored in the `shared_ptr`.
3. You can of course create a `std::unordered_map` keyed by `boost::posix::ptime`. You have two options: specialise `std::hash<boost::posix::ptime>`, or supply your own has functor to the `std::unordered_map`:

   ```
   struct TimeHash {
     std::size_t operator() (const boost::posix::ptime &t) const
     { return /* whatever */; }
   };

   std::unordered_map<boost::posix::ptime, AnyValueType, TimeHash> myMap;
   ```

---

Regarding the edit: all the standard specifies is that `std::hash<std::shared_ptr<T>>()(sp) == std::hash<T*>()(sp.get())` holds. In words, this means hashing a `std::shared_ptr` hashes the pointer stored in it (and not the control block, for example). *How exactly* the pointer is hashed depends entirely on the implementation, i.e. on your standard library vendor.

Comment: Angew: My question finally is more: how is the hashing function for a `shared_ptr<tT>`? the input is the raw adress 0xCBA... and the output the corresponding hash value?

Comment: Angew: I have edited massively my question, it is now precisely what I'm wondering .

Comment: @Guillaume07 Expanded the answer.